# How many ways are there to trace a user`s login and used commands in Linux after they deleted it (somehow)?

Tags: shell, redhat-enterprise-linux, command-history, recovery, remote-login

I am looking for a way to prove that my colleague at work did some changes to a configuration file while working with me on this case and now there are consequences because of his actions.

I checked the user history and saw that he connected to the server 5 times the same  day. But after searching for his .shistory in his /root folder there was just 1 history file with timestamps after the change of this config has been done.

Can I somehow find his root history or at least part of it? 
Also I checked last and there he was 5 times again. 
Bear in mind that I can't install any software on the servers and to clarify I am already aware of the deletion ways in the shell.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check his `~/.bash_history` file, and if missing his shell variable `HISTFILE`.

Comment: I know this won't help you, but that's why in some working environments, access to actual servers is restricted to be possible only through a bastion, whose main purpose is to log actions for accountability, to address your precise problem. Even if you're the only one to use it, if you can prove you always used it, then your actions are logged, and actions not logged aren't done by you. This requires of course that you don't have control of this bastion, or you could be able to tamper logs.

Answer (score 0):

If you had set up automated backups (e.g. via `crontab`), there might be snapshots of history files.

Then there is `lastlog` - quote: "(lastlog) reports the most recent login of all users or of a given user" (not a *command* history).

The files `/var/log/auth.log` or `/var/log/secure` might tell about use of `sudo`.

**But** even if you find a history file or log entries, it won't be conclusive proof *a certain person* did any changes. It just points to anyone with root access (or physical access)... this includes for example *you*.